# Return results from Redshift database based on IF condition in Python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I need to extract results from a `redshift database`  based on an `IF` condition written in Python.

Suppose I have a table with `CustomerID, SHipment Number, Invoice Station, ect` as columns in `Redshift  table`, I want to get all the records from Redshift table if customer ID exists which should be checked with user input.

- TABLE NAME = ShipmentInfo
- COLUMNS = CustomerID, BillNumber, Invoicing Station, Charges, etc.

Python

```
import psycopg2

con=psycopg2.connect(dbname= 'datamodel', host='123', 
                     port= '5439', user= 'bce', password= 'Ciz')

cur = con.cursor()
HWB = input("Enter the House Bill Number : ")

#if CustomerID = HWB:
cur.execute("SELECT source_system, file_nbr, file_date, CustomerID 
             FROM public.shipment_info where CustomerID = $HWB")

results = cur.fetchall()

cur.close() 
con.close()

print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider parameterization of user input value (else risk the infamous, [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)).

```py
# PREPARED STATEMENT WITH PLACEHOLDER
sql = """SELECT source_system, file_nbr, file_date, CustomerID 
         FROM public.shipment_info 
         WHERE CustomerID = %s
      """

# BIND PARAM VALUES WITH TUPLE OF ONE-ITEM
cur.execute(sql, (HWB,))
```